# What is with the splotches in the water in Beatriz at Dinner?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, beatriz-at-dinner

In [Beatriz at Dinner (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5929750/) I'm a little confused by the meaning behind the cloudy water spots in two scenes.

The first scene is right before the guests go inside. Beatriz is standing alone looking out over the water and notices a dark spot. I assume this is pollution? She stares at it for a while as the camera pans in and switches back to her face.

[image]

Later after dinner, when she is suspecting Doug Strutt as the man who built the hotel in her home town, there is a moment where she starts giving him a neck rub and she closes her eyes and we see some sort of flashback scene in which all that is seen is a pool of water with a small dark cloud that is expanding in it. After this she walks out abruptly and leaves Strutt alone.

[image]

These two scenes seem to be connected but I'm not following the message. What is the point of these two scenes to the overall plot?